# Heine and Borel's Lemma, Proof using Cantor's intersection theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was given the following theorem in a real-analysis course and its proof but I haven't fully understood it.

**Heine and Borel's Lemma:** Let $ a<b \in \mathbb{R} $. And let $ \{ U_\alpha \}_{ \alpha \in A }  $ be open sets on $ [a,b] $ where $ A $ is some set of indexes ( not necessarily countable ). Suppose they are a cover of $ [a,b] $ , meaning $ [a,b] \subset \cup_{ \alpha \in A }  U_\alpha  $. Then there exists a finite sub-covering, meaning there exists $ M \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ \alpha_1,..., \alpha_m \in A $ s.t.  $ [a,b] \subset \cup_{i=1}^M U_\alpha  $ .

**Proof:**
Suppose for the sake of contradiction, that $ [a,b] $ has no finite sub-covering.
Let us define by induction sequences $ \{ a_k \}  $ , $ \{ b_k \} $ s.t. $ a_k \leq b_k $ for all $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ , as follows:
$ a_0 = a , b_0 = b $. For every $ k \in \mathbb{N} $ we'll have $ b_k - a_k = \frac{b-a}{2^k} $. $ \{ a_n \}  $ monotonically increases , $ \{ b_n \}  $ monotonically decreases. By cantor's intersection theorem there exists a single $ x_0 \in \cap_{k=1}^{\infty} [a_k,b_k] $. Since $ U_{\alpha}   $ is a cover of $ [a,b] $ for all $ \alpha \in A $. then there exists $ \alpha_0 $ s.t. $ x_0 \in U_{\alpha_0} $ and since $ U_{\alpha_0 } $ is open, there exists $ \delta > 0 $ s.t. $ ( x_0 - \delta , x_0 + \delta ) \subset U_{\alpha_0} $, therefore there exists $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ s.t.  $ [ x_0 - \frac{b-a}{2^N} , x_0 + \frac{b-a}{2^N} ] \subset U_{\alpha_0} $  , specifically, since $ x_0 \in [a_N,b_N] $  and since $ b_N - a_N = \frac{b-a}{2^N} $ we'll have that $ [a_N,b_N ] \subset U_{\alpha_0} $, in contradiction to the construction in which there was no finite sub-covering for the sub-interval above.

**My question:**
I don't understand to what there's a contradiction? , when we supposed for contradiction that " $ [a,b] $ has no finite sub-covering " that means $ \forall M \in \mathbb{N}. \forall \alpha_1,..., \alpha_m \in A. [a,b] \not\subset \cup_{i=1}^M U_\alpha  $ , how does having $ [a_N,b_N ] \subset U_{\alpha_0} $ give me a contradiction to this logical statement?

Comment: I don't understand the proof either. I think it is not a valid proof.

Comment: I haven't learned yet about compact sets, and topology related stuff ( so I don't really know if there's a knowledge I'm missing to understand the proof ).  I also copied the proof from lecture notes ( as is ), I guess I'll ask my professor when he'll reach this proof in the lecture.